# warning: cannot represent an optional group of attributes; approximating

Tags: xml, angularjs, lxml, relaxng

I am getting this warning "warning: cannot represent an optional group of attributes; approximating" while converting the below Relax NG schema to XML schema using trang. I am not sure why this warning is coming. Is this something related to ordering of attributes? Please suggest a way to overcome this problem.

```
<define name="Relation">
    <element name="constraint">
      <attribute name="name">
        <data type="string"/>
      </attribute>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="relation">
          <choice>
            <value>&lt;&lt;</value>
            <value>&lt;=</value>
            <value>=</value>
            <value>&gt;=</value>
            <value>&gt;&gt;</value>
          </choice>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="version">
          <ref name="VirtualVersion"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </element>
  </define>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that XML Schema (xsd) does not allow you to make attributes optional *as a group*. The Relax NG schema is trying to specify that if `relation` is present then `version` must be present too, or they must both be absent. You can't have one without the other. XML Schema 1.0 has no way to represent this so `trang` generalizes to a schema that *will allow* one to appear without the other.  (In XSD 1.1, either assertions or conditional type assignment can be used to achieve this effect, but trang writes 1.0 not 1.1 XSD schemas.)

If you only want to get the warning to go away, you could change the Relax NG to:

```
<define name="Relation">
  <element name="constraint">
    <attribute name="name">
      <data type="string"/>
    </attribute>
    <optional>
      <attribute name="relation">
        <choice>
          <value>&lt;&lt;</value>
          <value>&lt;=</value>
          <value>=</value>
          <value>&gt;=</value>
          <value>&gt;&gt;</value>
        </choice>
      </attribute>
    </optional>
    <optional>
      <attribute name="version">
        <ref name="VirtualVersion"/>
      </attribute>
    </optional>
  </element>
</define>
```

which replicates what `trang` does when it generalizes the schema. Whatever application will receive the data after validation will have to perform a check to make sure that both `version` and `relation` are present if one of them is present at all.

Another way to do it, if you *can* change the number and type of attributes in your original Relax NG schema, would be to combine `relation` and `version` into a single attribute that an application would then have to parse. So instead of `relation='=' version='1.0'` you'd have, say, `version='=1.0'`. The application that receives this would then have to separate the value of `version` into `=` and `1.0`.